# Ubuntu 20.04 root password

Tags: ubuntu, password

I runned `sudo passwd -dl root` `sudo passwd -dl chris` then when i try to execute something like `sudo subl /etc/asound.conf`, a password is necessary to go. But the default password fails.

What can i do?

Comment: Have a look at `man sudo`. You need to provide your own password, and you need to have the appropriate rights set in /etc/sudoers. But since you deleted your password and the root password you can't do that anymore. In other words, you shot yourself in the foot, and now it hurts.

Comment: Time to boot from a live-cd then `chroot` to / partition and reset password